# Changes in header files (C++) are ignored?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, header, include

So recently I was working on my header files in C++ and something very strange came up. In my header files, I have my classes defined, here e.g. an audio player which uses an array of filenames to load sound samples:

```
#define NUM_WAVEFORMS 19

class AudioPlayer {
private:
    const char _waveFileNames[NUM_WAVEFORMS][40] = {"audio/startup_seq.wav", "audio/startup_warning.wav", 
                                        "audio/start_signal.wav", "audio/warning_person.wav",
                                        "audio/warning_bicycle.wav", "audio/warning_car.wav",
                                        "audio/warning_motorcycle.wav", "audio/warning_bus.wav",
                                        "audio/warning_trafficlight_red.wav", "audio/warning_trafficlight_green.wav",
                                        "audio/warning_sidewalk.wav", "audio/warning_uphill.wav",
                                        "audio/warning_downhill.wav", "audio/suggestion_bench.wav",
                                        "audio/suggestion_chair.wav", "audio/suggestion_bin.wav",
                                        "audio/to_day.wav", "audio/to_night.wav", "audio/to_park.wav"};
    Mix_Chunk* _sample[NUM_WAVEFORMS];
public:
...
```

Now what I noticed is when I change my array of filenames, rename elements or ad new ones, this changes are not applied when compiling. When I print the elements of the array in my main .cpp-file, I get wrong indexes and elements because the array is in a previous state. When I change the length of the array by 1 and try to legit access the last element, it gives me a segmentation fault, meaning it assumes it doesn't exist. What is going on here? I have a feeling my header files don't get compiled properly.

Here's my CMakeLists.txt: (Yolo_with_Opencv is my main C++ file)

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)
include(FindPkgConfig)

project (Yolo_with_Opencv)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -pthread")
set (source_dir "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/")
SET (OpenCV_DIR "/home/installation/OpenCV-3.3.1/opencv/include/opencv2")

file (GLOB source_files "${source_dir}/Yolo_with_Opencv.cpp")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_Mixer REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET SDL2_mixer)
find_package(ALSA REQUIRED)
include_directories(${ALSA_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable (Yolo_with_Opencv ${source_files})
target_include_directories(Yolo_with_Opencv PRIVATE ${source_dir})
target_link_libraries(Yolo_with_Opencv ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(Yolo_with_Opencv ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(Yolo_with_Opencv PkgConfig::SDL2_Mixer)
target_link_libraries(Yolo_with_Opencv ${ALSA_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(Yolo_with_Opencv i2c)
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is not possible to tell what the issue is without having your setup available to us.  It could be that you're not issuing a clean build, you edited the wrong file(s), or if your program has bugs that always existed, but now you're seeing the manifestations of those bugs.

Comment: What proof can you show that when you change the header file, ***every*** `cpp` that includes that header file gets recompiled, and relinked?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can say for certain that I have not edited the wrong file and also that it is not because bugs. What Do you mean with "issuing a clean build"?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I can't, that's why I asked the question. How can I do that?

Comment: Well, you need to figure this out yourself. Nobody except you can log which files get compiled when you change the header file.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Yeah, but is there a command or anything to monitor? I use Cmake with Codelite and CmakeLists.txt

Comment: I'm sure that every time a compiler get executed, the command gets logged. You need to simply make sure that every cpp file that should get recompiled actually gets recompiled, and if not, figure out why not. This is something that you have to do yourself. There is no "command or anything" that will do everything for you. This is a part of what it takes to develop complicated code.

Comment: CMake has functionality for header dependency scanning. What generator are you using, and what CMake version do you have installed (I know your project minimum is 3.5, but I'm asking for the version you are _running_)? Maybe something about your header file is confusing the dependency scanner. Can you show some of the top of that header file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the reason why cmake does not monitor changes of your file is that the file is not added to the target as dependency. You defined source_fles as a single cpp file. Add your header file to the source_file variable and any changes in the file will trigger recompiling.